# SQL Stored Procedure data type for list of rows

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g, multiple-return-values

What data type can I use to store all rows found by SELECT query?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE handleFailedCalls(xNumber in varchar(10)) AS
result {DATA TYPE I WANT};
BEGIN
   select * into result
   from CALLS c1
   where c1.status = 'fail'
END
/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [BULK COLLECT](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems045.htm), example:

> ```
> DECLARE
> TYPE emp_typ IS TABLE OF employees%ROWTYPE INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
> all_employees emp_typ;
> BEGIN
> SELECT * BULK COLLECT INTO all_employees FROM employees;
> ```
>
> A SELECT ... BULK COLLECT INTO statement can return multiple rows. You must set up collection variables to hold the results. You can declare associative arrays or nested tables that grow as needed to hold the entire result set.

Comment: What if I BULK COLLECT this way with selecting data from joint table like `employees LEFT JOIN users` ? Will there be all columns of both tables in all_employees?

Comment: @ShaahinShemshian see https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/oracle-plsql-best/0596001215/re73.html

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use a `REFCURSOR` variable of `OUT` type.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE handleFailedCalls(xNumber in varchar2,
p_result OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
) AS
BEGIN
   OPEN p_result FOR select * from CALLS c1
   where c1.status = 'fail'
END
/
```

Also, use `VARCHAR2` instead of `VARCHAR`. It should be without the size, as procedure arguments with size won't compile.

The procedure can be called to receive the cursor into a local `ref cursor` variable.

```
DECLARE
res_cur SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
    handleFailedCalls('Xnumber1', res_cur );
END;
/
```